# Unable to load rule assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, static-code-analysis

I have created a live code analyser using sdk template in Visual studio 2015 RC(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx). I was able to create nuget package out of it and install the same into class library(Created this using VS 2015 RTM). Live code analyser is working like a charm.

I tried to create a ruleset for the same and tried to integrate the same in the build of the project by changing the property of the project.

Problem started from there. I am getting the message below

> 1> Running Code Analysis...
>    1>MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly 'c:\myprojects\classlibrary1\packages\eyanalyser.1.0.0.7\tools\analyzers\eyanalyser.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>    1>MSBUILD : warning : CA0064 : No analysis was performed because the specified rule set could not be loaded or did not contain any managed code analysis rules.

```
 <RuleSet Name="Project WizBang Rules" ToolsVersion="1.1">
 <RuleHintPaths>
 <Path>C:\MyProjects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EYAnalyser.1.0.0.7\tools\analyzers</Path>
 </RuleHintPaths>
 <Rules AnalyzerId="EYAnalyser" RuleNamespace="EYAnalyser">
 <Rule Id="3.4 NameSpace" Action="Warning" />
 <Rule Id="4.2 Class" Action="Warning" />
 <Rule Id="4.6 Field Naming" Action="Warning" />
 </Rules>
 </RuleSet> '''
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

This is the exception thrown. What you should do is investigate the `LoaderExceptions` to see what exactly went wrong. My guess is that an assembly is missing from the package you have created, so it loads assembly A, but A needs B and B isn't present. You should fix that and then the issue will be over.

Comment: I have created the same as a nugget package which  had only one dll in it. After installing the nugget package into a project, the live code analysis works fine. Applying the same as ruleset in the build cause the issue.

Comment: And that doesn't have any dependencies? What do the `LoaderExceptions` say?

Comment: I tried to load the assembly using Assembly.Load, but didn't through any error.

Comment: Update: On further investigation
I tried to load the assembly in the nugget package using Assembly.Load(), although the load was successful. I could see the error in assembly DefinedTypes.LoaderExceptions, 

{"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

Comment: So there is indeed missing an assembly. You should distribute that too, demand it is already there or make a dependency on it (don't know how).